How do I Get rid of '0' in index column?
I try to rename the Index column to 'idx' and get rid of 0 using this code:
df1.index.rename(name='idx', inplace=True)

However, I end up with the second dataframe as below. It results in messing up my boxplot by creating an empty plot of index column. Please guide me. Thank you.



0
Company_A
Company_B




1
9.3
11.0


2
8.8
9.8






0
Company_A
Company_B




idx




1
9.3
11.0


2
8.8
9.8




Given the output of df1.index.rename(name='idx', inplace=True), it appears that 0 is the name of df1.columns rather than of df1.index. Use: df1.rename_axis(columns=None, inplace=True). However, it's not clear how that will help you create your boxplot. It shouldn't matter if your axes have a name. So, you should probably review your implementation for the boxplot. If you need help with that, please provide a proper [mre].

Thank you for your response. It makes me understand of index mechanism. And yeah it turns out the the boxplot does not associate with the index issues.
